# Rails 3.2.6 route no longer working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've been building an app in 3.2.3 and it's working fine, as soon as I upgraded to 3.2.6 to address a security vulnerability one of my routes stopped working.

It's a simple view, when I click edit on a block object it brings me to the edit screen.  However when I make changes and hit submit I receive this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"units", :id=>nil}
```

In my controller there is an edit and update action:

```
def edit
    @units = Unit.find(params[:id])
  end

def update
    @units = Unit.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @units.update_attributes(params[:unit])
        format.html { redirect_to @units, notice: 'Unit was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @units.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

On the update action, if I change redirect_to @units to redirect_to units_path the error goes away.  Has something changed in 3.2.6 that won't let you redirect as I have been?  I have another controller with the exact same edit and update action and it works fine as is.

I have two laptops one with 3.2.3 the other with 3.2.6.  3.2.3 works fine but as soon as I upgraded it I got the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you please should your view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a similar problem was reported from [redmine](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6585)... but it's really a matter of a bug in your own code that has been exposed.  Somewhere you have a nil being passed to a path function, which should always have been an error but wasn't, and instead caught other parameters on the request to use (which sometimes did the right thing).

Read through that link to get the full scoop.

I'm not sure looking at this bit of code if it truly lies here without seeing the full stack trace... It's hard to imagine `@units` being nil at that point, so there may be something else involved.

It's not super critical, but in your naming conventions, `@unit` would be more appropriate for edit and update actions, instead of `@units`, since there should only be one unit being edited.  What is the name of the controller?

Comment: Thanks DGM.  I changed my naming conventions to @unit and the respective view code.  The controller name is units_controller.  I guess now I have to figure out what was causing it to pass a nil.  I can get past it, but I'm wanting to make sure it doesn't bite me in the arse later on.

Comment: I'm wondering if the real error is on your show page, maybe where you have an edit_units_path()  call.   I bet the value in that call is nil.

Comment: OR... has no id field.  Does Unit have the default primary key named id?

Comment: edit_unit_path(@unit) is in the show view.  Unit does have a default primary key named id as the rest of my models do.

Comment: This threw me for a loop as well when I updated. Pay close attention to the backtrace... it will help you find the offending view code.